# Java: JOptionPane Radio Buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, input, joptionpane

I'm working on a simple program to help me calculate stuff for mixing eLiquid. I am trying to add radio buttons within JOptionPane.showInputDialog but I can't link them together. When I run the program, nothing comes up. This is all I have:

```
JRadioButton nicSelect = new JRadioButton("What is the target Nicotine level? ");
        JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("0");
        JRadioButton b2 = new JRadioButton("3");
        JRadioButton b3 = new JRadioButton("6");
        JRadioButton b4 = new JRadioButton("12");
        JRadioButton b5 = new JRadioButton("18");
        JRadioButton b6 = new JRadioButton("24");
```

Comment: As an alternative, consider using a JComboBox as described in the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I [offer a `JSpinner`](http://forums.aussievapers.com/diy-juice-recipes-mixing/28538-e-juice-mixing-calculator-needs-testing.html) for the nic. level (and it stops at **36mg/ml**).

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to using several `JRadioButton`'s, you can provide a selection interface via a `JComboBox` by passing a String array to the JOptionPane.showInputDialog:

```
String[] values = {"0", "3", "6", "12", "18", "24"};

Object selected = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the target Nicotine level?", "Selection", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, values, "0");
if ( selected != null ){//null if the user cancels. 
    String selectedString = selected.toString();
    //do something
}else{
    System.out.println("User cancelled");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom panel and present any options you like, for example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("1");
        final JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("2");

        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but how can I add a message to go along with the buttons?

Comment: @NicolaDaaboul Just add a `JLabel` in there somewhere.  `panel.add(new JLabel("My Message");`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Also if button1 was chosen for example, can I do something like this? 

if(button1 == true) {

*do some code*

}

Comment: @NicolaDaaboul add a change listener

Comment: @NicolaDaaboul , Use `if(button1.isSelected())` in the change listener.